# adaptive elliptical structuring element in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ellipse, mathematical-morphology

I'm trying to create an adaptive elliptical structuring element for an image to dilate or erode it. I write this code but unfortunately all of the structuring elements are `ones(2*M+1)`.

```
I = input('Enter the input image: ');
M = input('Enter the maximum allowed semi-major axes length: ');

% determining ellipse parameteres from eigen value decomposition of LST

row = size(I,1);
col = size(I,2);
SE = cell(row,col);
padI = padarray(I,[M M],'replicate','both');
padrow = size(padI,1);
padcol = size(padI,2);

for m = M+1:padrow-M
   for n = M+1:padcol-M

      a = (l2(m-M,n-M)+eps/l1(m-M,n-M)+l2(m-M,n-M)+2*eps)*M;
      b = (l1(m-M,n-M)+eps/l1(m-M,n-M)+l2(m-M,n-M)+2*eps)*M;

      if e1(m-M,n-M,1)==0
         phi = pi/2;
      else
         phi = atan(e1(m-M,n-M,2)/e1(m-M,n-M,1));
      end

      % defining structuring element for each pixel of image

      x0 = m;  
      y0 = n;
      se = zeros(2*M+1);
      row_se = 0;
      for i = x0-M:x0+M
         row_se = row_se+1;
         col_se = 0;
         for j = y0-M:y0+M
            col_se = col_se+1;
            x = j-y0;
            y = x0-i;
            if ((x*cos(phi)+y*sin(phi))^2)/a^2+((x*sin(phi)-y*cos(phi))^2)/b^2 <= 1
               se(row_se,col_se) = 1;
            end
         end
      end

      SE{m-M,n-M} = se;
   end
end
```

`a`, `b` and `phi` are semi-major and semi-minor axes length and phi is angle between `a` and x axis.

I used 2 MATLAB functions to compute the Local Structure Tensor of the image, and then its eigenvalues and eigenvectors for each pixel. These are the matrices `l1`, `l2`, `e1` and `e2`.

Comment: This is not complete code. Where are `l1`, `l2` and `e1` defined? -- Don't use `atan`, use `atan2`. -- Why do you do `for i = x0-M:x0+M` and then `y = x0-i`, instead of `for y = -M:M`?

Comment: The error in your code is probably (without being able to see `l1` and `l2` etc.) that `a` and `b` are larger than M.

Comment: In addition to @CrisLuengo's comment, dividing `eps` is generally not a good idea. What are you trying to do with `eps`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Thank you for your help. I used 2 matlab function to compute Local Structure Tensor of image and then eigen values and eigen vectors of it, i.e. `l1`, `l2`, `e1` and `e2` for each pixel.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I use `i = x0-M:x0+M` because I want to relate coordinate system, i.e. `x` and `y` to rows and columns of image in a specific neighborhood, i.e. `[M M]` of each pixel, i.e. `x0` and `y0`.

Comment: @Yvon: Thanks. division by zero and perfectly smoothed regions are handled by adding a small positive number, i.e. `eps` to eigen values. this is expressed in my reference paper.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Okay. you're right. I can use `y = -M:M` instead of `i = x0-M:x0+M` and `y = x0-i`. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Still `eps/l1(m-M,n-M)` looks very unreasonable to me. I think @CrisLuengo has had an answer to this.

Comment: Could you provide a way to get `l1` `l2` `e1` and `e2` so we can actually run your code? If the actual calculation is too long then could you make up some dummy values that go into the right range? I ask this because we do have a [mcve] requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the bit of your code I didn't understand:

> ```
> a = (l2(m-M,n-M)+eps/l1(m-M,n-M)+l2(m-M,n-M)+2*eps)*M;
> b = (l1(m-M,n-M)+eps/l1(m-M,n-M)+l2(m-M,n-M)+2*eps)*M;
> ```

I simplified the expression for `b` to (just removing the indexing):

```
b = (l1+eps/l1+l2+2*eps)*M;
```

For `l1` and `l2` in the normal range we get:

```
b =(approx)= (l1+0/l1+l2+2*0)*M = (l1+l2)*M;
```

Thus, `b` can easily be larger than `M`, which I don't think is your intention. The `eps` in this case also doesn't protect against division by zero, which is typically the purpose of adding `eps`: if `l1` is zero, `eps/l1` is `Inf`.

Looking at this expression, it seems to me that you intended this instead:

```
b = (l1+eps)/(l1+l2+2*eps)*M;
```

Here, you're adding `eps` to each of the eigenvalues, making them guaranteed non-zero (the structure tensor is symmetric, positive semi-definite). Then you're dividing `l1` by the sum of eigenvalues, and multiplying by `M`, which leads to a value between `0` and `M` for each of the axes.

So, this seems to be a case of misplaced parenthesis.

Just for the record, this is what you need in your code:

```
a = (l2(m-M,n-M)+eps ) / ( l1(m-M,n-M)+l2(m-M,n-M)+2*eps)*M;
b = (l1(m-M,n-M)+eps ) / ( l1(m-M,n-M)+l2(m-M,n-M)+2*eps)*M;
                     ^   ^
                added parentheses
```

---

Note that you can simplify your code by defining, outside of the loops:

```
[se_x,se_y] = meshgrid(-M:M,-M:M);
```

The inner two loops, over `i` and `j`, to construct `se` can then be written simply as:

```
se = ((se_x.*cos(phi)+se_y.*sin(phi)).^2)./a.^2 + ...
     ((se_x.*sin(phi)-se_y.*cos(phi)).^2)./b.^2 <= 1;
```

(Note the `.*` and `.^` operators, these do element-wise multiplication and power.)

A further slight improvement comes from realizing that `phi` is first computed from `e1(m,n,1)` and `e1(m,n,2)`, and then used in calls to `cos` and `sin`. If we assume that the eigenvector is properly normalized, then

```
cos(phi) == e1(m,n,1)
sin(phi) == e1(m,n,2)
```

But you can always make sure they are normalized:

```
cos_phi = e1(m-M,n-M,1);
sin_phi = e1(m-M,n-M,2);
len = hypot(cos_phi,sin_phi);
cos_phi = cos_phi / len;
sin_phi = sin_phi / len;
se = ((se_x.*cos_phi+se_y.*sin_phi).^2)./a.^2 + ...
     ((se_x.*sin_phi-se_y.*cos_phi).^2)./b.^2 <= 1;
```

Considering trigonometric operations are fairly expensive, this should speed up your code a bit.

Comment: Seems like you answered my question. OP didn't want to divide `eps` itself by a number, which I think provides little help to the calculation.

Comment: Oh by the way it would be better if you use `l1 + eps(l1)` and so on. `eps` with no input argument defaults to `eps(1)`, which is the smallest number _to be added_ into `1` to make the sum different than `1`. Now consider the case where `abs(l1) < eps(1)`. Eg. `l1=1e-30` and `l2=2e-30` and `l1/l2` is not a divide-by-zero operation.

Comment: @Yvon What does `eps(0)` do? The point is not to create something slightly larger that `l1`, but to ensure `l1` is not 0.

Comment: `eps(0) = 4.9407e-324` and `1/eps(0) = Inf`  Also if `l1 = 1e-30; l2 = 2e-30;` then `l1/l2 = 0.5000` and `l1/(l2+eps) = 4.5036e-15`

Comment: @Yvon: the eigenvalues of the structure tensor are the same order of magnitude as the square of the gradient of the image. So if `l1 = 1e-30`, it can be considered 0 (anything below 1e-6 is a rounding error to me in these cases). I would actually implement this simply as `l1/(l1+l2+1e-6)` or something like that. The other alternative is to do a point-wise minimum `l1=min(l1,1e-6)`.

Comment: does that affect the result `se`

Comment: @Yvon: I wouldn't think so. The idea is to have a round SE (filter kernel) when the two eigenvalues are similar (which means there is no preferred direction locally in the image), and make it increasingly elongated the larger the difference between the two eigenvalues (i.e. there is a preferred orientation). When both eigenvalues are very small, the image is locally uniform, and the filtering will have little effect no matter what the filter shape.

Comment: @Yvon: If you're interested, [this is the paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016786551300192X) that describes the method that the OP is trying to implement. There's [a PDF here](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:978502/FULLTEXT01.pdf). This paper states "Divisions  by  zero  [in]  perfectly  smooth  regions  are  handled by  adding  a  small  positive  number  to  the  eigenvalues  (small enough to be neglected for any other purpose, i.e. machine epsilon)."

Comment: hmm if they don't care about operations upon very small values then probably it's okay to do this way. It's good to rule this thing out of OP's problem.

Comment: @Cris Luengo: Thanks for your great help. I used this expression:        `a = (l2(m-M,n-M)+eps/l1(m-M,n-M)+l2(m-M,n-M)+2*eps)*M;`                     because I forced to pad my image for bordering pixels neighborhood:                               `padI = padarray(I,[M M],'replicate','both');`                                              but I calculated eigen values and eigen vectors before and save them in a matrix with the size of the original image. I mean `l1,l2,e1, e2(1,1)` are correspond to the pixel `m = M+1, n = M+1` in the padded image.

Comment: @bahar: I understand the indexing, I removed that from the answer to make things simpler. It helped me understand the equation you were trying to implement. Does adding the brackets solve your problem? If so, please accept the answer so that it's clear your problem is solved. I see that you have quite a few questions on SO and haven't accepted any answers. Please go through them and accept answers if they were helpful. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/376604

Comment: @CrisLuengo: sorry. I didn't know to accept the answers. Thank you very much. I could create the structuring elements with your help. Unfortunately i can't do adaptive dilation with those SE's using matlab 'imdilate' and get an output image. Have you any idea?

Comment: @bahar: That's true, standard dilation algorithms assume a fixed SE. You'll have to implement your own dilation to use your adaptive SE. It's not as hard as it looks. For each output pixel, place your specific SE at its center, and read all the input pixels it overlays. Then take the maximum value of those pixels and use that as the output value. You do need a separate output image, you cannot write in the input image while you do this! If you have trouble getting this implemented, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: @bahar: At the risk of encouraging you posting questions as answers (the answer box is to answer questions, not ask them): Your problem is in the line `W = SE{i-M,j-M}.*padf(i-M:i+M,i-M:i+M);`. You're using `i` to index in both directions! Furthermore, by multiplying with the SE, your `min` will always be 0. You need to use the SE to index: `W = padf(...); W = W(SE{...});`.