# adaptive erosion and dilation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I am implementing adaptive dilation and erosion. This is a follow-up question from [this earlier one.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50011496/7328782) I wrote this code:

```
%% dilation and erosion

f = input('Enter the input image for dilation: ');
f_dil = zeros(size(f));
f_ero = zeros(size(f));
padf = padarray(f,[M M],'replicate','both');
padfrow = size(padf,1);
padfcol = size(padf,2);

for i = M+1:padfrow-M
    for j = M+1:padfcol-M
       W = SE{i-M,j-M}.*padf(i-M:i+M,i-M:i+M);
       f_dil(i-M,j-M) = max(max(W));
       f_ero(i-M,j-M) = min(min(W));
    end
end
```

But i don't attain a good eroded and dilated results. I don't know maybe the code used to compute LST and eigen values has a problem!

These are a sample image and its dilation with my code:

[image: tire.tif]

[image: tire_dil.tif]

Comment: Please, when you post a question, provide proper context so people can understand what you are doing. You cannot tag people in questions or answers, only in comments, and only specific people that have commented to that same post. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/376604

Comment: @Cris Luengo: Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the line

```
W = SE{i-M,j-M}.*padf(i-M:i+M,i-M:i+M);
```

You're using `i` to index in both directions of the image. There needs to be a `j` in there.

Furthermore, by multiplying with the SE, your min will always be 0, which will cause the erosion to be all black. You need to use the SE to index:

```
W = padf(i-M:i+M,j-M:j+M);
W = W(SE{i-M,j-M});
```